# How could I remove unnecessary characters in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need a query that could remove unnecessary characters (a not-so-needed trailing comma as an example) from the string stored in my database table.

So that

```
EMAIL_ADD
abc@gmail.com,
abc@yahoo.com,def@example.org,
abs-def@ac.uk,
```

would update it into something like this:

```
EMAIL_ADD
abc@gmail.com
abc@yahoo.com,def@example.org
abs-def@ac.uk
```

Comment: Are you specifically talking about removing trailing character? How do you identify which characters are unnecessary?

Comment: What about removing these characters when/before writing them to the database? Otherwise you will always have the issue to remove them when reading data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `TRIM()` function with `TRAILING` option removes a specific unwanted character from end of string , in your case being a comma present at end.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET EMAIL_ADD = TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM EMAIL_ADD)
```

[**See documentation here TRIM()**](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific list of characters to filter out at the start and end use `trim` functions:

```
select ltrim(ltrim(rtrim(rtrim(email_add, ','), ' '), ','), ' ')
from   tableX
```

Here I nested `ltrim` and `rtrim` to remove leading and trailing `,` and .

Or using `trim`:

```
select trim(trim(both ',' from email_add))
from   tableX
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only whant to remove the last character of a string you can use

```
update mytable set my_column = substr(my_column ,0,len(trim(my_column)-1) where mycolumn like '%,'
```

It is an untested example.